# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `Data`.`company_eligibilities` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-migrations

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('company_eligibilities', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('marks');
            $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('company_id')
                ->references('id')->on('companies')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('company_eligibilities');
    }
```

Company migration already did before executing the above migration

I am getting the above error when I am trying to create a table along with the foreign key. Have I done something wrong ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that, you migrate `companies` before migrate `company_eligibilities`, change your foreign key id to
**unsigned big integer**, Laravel 5.8 make default foreign key   as unsigned big integer, also for **6.x** and **7.x** :

```
$table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
```

Or,

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('company_id');
```